# Running command.com or cmd.exe from VBA causing problems with MSG command

Tags: windows, vba, cmd

I cannot get msg to work when I open the command prompt from within VBA, however have proved that it works when launching cmd.exe or "command prompt" from windows.

My VBA code is as follows:

```
Sub test()
Dim str_to_pass As String

str_to_pass = "msg"

Call Shell("cmd.exe /s /k " & str_to_pass, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

my result from inside command prompt: "'msg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,..."

however if I open command prompt, or cmd.exe from windows first, and then type "msg" I get the prompt for the syntax of how to use msg.

So, how can I access this usability of the command prompt from vba, and further, why are the commands different depending on how cmd.exe is launched?

Comment: adding to the confusion, I created a section of code to create a batch file of the shell command and then run that bat file instead of trying to call shell.  It makes the batch file, and the batch file works if I open it from outside VBA, however when I open the batch programmatically from vba I get the same result as before.

Comment: Enter `where msg` at the command prompt and change `str_to_pass` to the full pathname it prints.

Comment: It is likely in Windows\System32. That's where mine is, and entering the full path to the .exe still produces the same error message. (I was mad that my boss made me do actual work because this is the thing I wanted to work on today!) This is a really good question.

Comment: Oh, btw, I did notice that the environment variables of the cmd window that Shell opens are different than those of a cmd window I manually open.

Comment: I tried the where msg suggestion, delivers the same results.  From inside the cmd prompt that vba launches through shell, I cannot access msg, even with the full path name c:\windows\system32\msg.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the way 64-bit Windows directs calls to and from 32-bit applications. Windows has a virtual folder called `SysNative` folder that needs to be used in place of `System32` when accessing 64-bit executables from 32-bit applications. Here's a great explanation: http://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm

The code needs to be:

```
str_to_pass = "c:\windows\sysnative\msg"
Call Shell("cmd.exe /s /k " & str_to_pass, vbNormalFocus)
```

And here's the related MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx